# Поиск слова по шаблону из строки в java?(Алгоритм)

Tags: java

Не въезжаю в алгоритм.
Есть строка:

`String My_String = "Привет, как дела? Что с погодой, а-за-за?";`

Нужен алгоритм поиска (метод java), который бы искал в данной строке слова по
шаблону "абв", таким образом он пихал бы в массив `MyArray` два слова, внимание,

`MyArray[0]= "как";`

`MyArray[1]= "что";`

То есть, я думаю так:

1. Метод должен выглядеть так `MySearch(String MyPattern, char[] MyABC){... }`. Где `MyPattern'ом` может быть формула например `"абв"`.Где `char MyABC[]` - алфавит (набор символов из которых состоит проверяемая `MyString`)
2. Если я правильно понял, то все должно сводится к проверке типа "абвбвв"
   Например, это будет слово "Вереск", т.е. если буква повторяется, то она
   будет такой же, как и по счету в алфавите.
3. Если я правильно понимаю? то должен быть цикл в цикле, как минимум, но как
   это работает пока не доходит. Мои попытки не увенчались успехом.
4. Нужен именно ручной метод, а не встроенный, чтобы его можно было
   подкорректировать,

Ребят, помогите мне с **ручным алгоритмом** на **java**? Только не минусуйте меня, просто скажите в комментах, что не то, я подредактирую.)

Comment: непонятно, почему при поиске по исходной строке по шаблону абв находит 2 слова : как и что? если просто набор искомых букв, то в слове привет есть буква в... и зачем вам массив с алфавитом?

Comment: КАТ, ДЖАТ, ЛАД, ГАД!
@Дмитрий Алфавиты будут разными, следовательно формула тоже разная,"АБВ" - это формула по которой можно найти до х...я, Где "x"-первая буква, а "я"- слов например " кот, ток, лад, лук, луг, гул" и т.д. и до х...я еще слов. А вот для слов "LADY, BABY, GATE"... как вы уже догадались будет паттерн "ABCD". Мне важно, чтобы метод для проверки брал разные массивы символов!Спасибо. – Arthur Alunts 5 минут

Comment: я не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду по словом "паттерн" и какое отношение он имеет к исходной строке в вашем вопросе - Привет как дела, что с погодой а-за-за-за??

Comment: Хорошо, Вы в МТС, Вы выбираете номер говорите мне золотой, Консультант пишет у себя паттерн __+79222116677__
и находит по этому паттерну:
+79222445511
+79222443322
+79222115511
Формула же стандартная выглядит так для паттерна: 
+12333445566
OK. Ничего что я с вами по английски разговариваю? OK?
У меня же вместо цифр буквы!)))))))

Comment: Прикиньте случайно удалил ответ.) Выручайте что делать?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, вызываю твой дух!

Comment: Вам нужен алгоритм поиска подстроки. Существует куча алгоритмов от решения влоб до алгоритма Кнута, Морриса и Пратта. Выбирайте любой и реализуйте, благо для каждого алгоритма можно найти не только описание и даже пример реализации псевдокодом. В википедии довольно подробно описанные все существующие алгоритмы. [См тут.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Поиск_подстроки)

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, вы дошли до того этапа, когда придется учить регулярные выражения `:)`

Вот несколько полезных ссылок:

- [Прекрасная шпаргалка, если вдруг что-то забылось](http://website-lab.ru/article/regexp/shpargalka_po_regulyarnyim_vyirajeniyam/)
- [Регулярные выражения в Java](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-v-java)
- [Сайт для тестирования регулярных выражний](https://regex101.com/)

---

Теперь можно и писать код:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        final String someText = "Привет как дела, что с погодой за-за-за?";

        Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("\\b[а-я]{3}\\b");

        Matcher match = regexp.matcher(someText);
        while(match.find()) {
            System.out.println(match.group());
        }
}
```

Вывод:

> как
> что

Пожалуй, распишу немного подробнее:

- Создаем объект класса `Pattern` - это и есть наше регулярное выражение
- Объект `Matcher` - это все совпадения по данному выражению
- `while(match.find())` перебирает все результаты и выводит на консоль

---

И разберем регулярку:

```
\b[а-я]{3}\b
```

- `\b` - это обозначение границы слова
- `[а-я]` - все строчные русские буквы
- `{3}` - требуемое количество количество букв

В итоге получаем: *подойдут любые слова из строчных русских букв, длиной ровно 3 символа*

---

> Нужно чтобы искались слова с Только с первой буквой -Любой- а вторая и третья Любая но не первая, а вторая, иными словами "ABB", например как в слове "Kaa" или "Маа"

Вот такая получилась регулярка:

```
\b(\p{L})((?!\1)\p{L})\2\b
```

Разберем подробнее:

- `\p{L}` - любой *UTF-8* символ
- `(?!\1)\p{L}` это отрицательный просмотр назад. Он проверяет, что захват по маске `\p{L}` не равен захвату предыдущей группы (скобки вокруг первого `\p{L}` нужны для того, чтобы создать из него группу). Проще говоря, он проверяет, что второй символ не равен первому.
- `((?!\1)\p{L})\2` соответствует символу, который попал во вторую группу. То есть 2 и 3 символы повторяются.

Вот и получается: *строка из 3 символов; первый любой, второй любой, но не равен первому, третий равен второму*

Comment: Привет Стас, что случилось сейчас, сейчас. 
Спасибо, но увы мне нужен собственный ручной перебор я написал об этом в п. "4. Нужен именно ручной метод, а не встроенный, чтобы его можно было подкорректировать алгоритм," Тем более что длина паттерна может варьировать от 1 до 100 и более. Спасибо, но ваш метод не подходит. Извините.)

Comment: Хотя может быть и подойдет, как мне сказать, чтобы искались слова с Только с первой буквой -Любой- а вторая и третья Любая но не первая, а вторая, иными словами "ABB", например как в слове "Kaa" или "Маа"?

Comment: @ArthurAlunts добавил. Надеюсь, поможет)